# Spark Dataset: how to change alias of the columns after a flatmap?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have two spark datasets that I'm trying to join. The join keys are nested in dataset A, so I must flatmap it out first before joining with dataset B. The problem is that as soon as I flatmap that field, the column name becomes the default "_1", "_2", etc. Is it possible to change the alias somehow?

`A.flatMap(a => a.keys).join(B).where(...)`

Comment: can you copy your code,not sure why you need alias in flatmap

Answer (score 2):

After applying the transformation like `flatMap` you lose the columns as which is logical as after applying transformation like `flatMap` or `map` it does not guarantee that the number of column or datatype inside each column remain the same.That's why we lose the column name there.

What you can do is you can fetch all previous column and then apply it to the dataset like this:-

```
val columns =  A.columns
A.flatMap(a => a.keys).toDF(columns:_ *).join(B).where(...)
```

this will only work if the number of columns is same after applying `flatmap`

Hope this clears your issue

Thanks